# Upload picture status is gone or hard to find

Tags: feature-request, images, imgur, uploader

When uploading a picture to SE, the dialog in the middle of the screen will have this loading sequence:

o..
.o.
..o

However, the actual percent uploaded is displayed in the bottom left of the screen, just like the **Sending request** messages.

I think it would be much better if the percent uploaded was in the dialog, which is much easier to see.

This was viewed using Lubuntu 12.04 and Chromium.

On Mac OS 10.5 with Safari the upload percentage is not visible at all.

Can we add the percentage in the dialog as a feature?

Comment: As a small by-the-way, the % uploaded is a Chrome feature not the website.

Comment: Ooh. I've been getting the royal treatment, then.

Comment: This is nearly instantaneous to me on every connection I've ever had, including ridiculously slow Wi-Fi or non-3G mobile service. How long are you waiting to upload images? And how large are those images?!

Comment: The images are large once in a while (screenshots), but not as large as [this picture](http://boingboing.net/2012/09/19/xkcds-14-foot-wide-click-and.html). And my connection isn't that great. I suppose other people may have pretty bad connections, and you don't really lose if the progress bar goes from 0 to 100 in 0.3 s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upload percentage tracking is handled as a feature of Chrome, hence not seeing it on Safari. This is not a bug *per se*, but instead a pure feature request if you'd like the percentage displayed across all browsers (the feasibility of which I cannot attest to).

Comment: But the second part is a bug, right?

Comment: @BlueIce The second part should be posted separate from the first.

Comment: Ok, edited. I will ask that later.

Comment: Alrighty then! I think this would be a great feature!